# Why (and how) to verify the signature of a download?

Tags: signature

I have downloaded rsync from the [official page](https://rsync.samba.org).
Each rsync download is associated with a signature.

First, why should I check the signature? What am I risking if not doing that? I assume that if someone is able to inject malicious code to the website, then is also able to generate a new signature and replace the original one.

Second, how do I verify the signature with a command line tool? In my system I have got `gpg` installed, can I used that?

Comment: "how do I verify the signature?" With PGP.

Comment: I already saw that link before posting this question, it does not show an answer with a command line tool (I am editing the question to specify that I would like a command line tool, I was not clear), and the first point of my question is not explained. Please unmark the question.

Comment: RTFM - A simple search returns [Making and verifying signatures](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html)

Comment: The rest of your question is opinion based and off-topic.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the purpose of putting the signature in that website (o link me something which explain that?), really I do not know. What is the author of the site trying to avoid? A man in the middle attack in which only the file is changed?

Comment: BTW, I already saw your second link before posting the answer and I can't get it working

Comment: Please do some research. Start by reading [Does a PGP signature provide integrity verification?](//security.stackexchange.com/q/56593)

Comment: Only the owner of the PGP key can create a valid signature so if the signature is valid it proves that the file was created by the owner and not modified.